# Only highlight required fields without showing an error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have this property in my model:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(40,ErrorMessage = "First Name must not be more than 40 characters.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

and my view code:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

If the user doesn't enter a value for the field, I want the textbox to be highlighted but I don't want an error message to be displayed. I need the error messages for the other validations to still be displayed.

If I leave the code as is, the default error message is displayed

> The FirstName field is required.

If I change the required attribute to be [Required(ErrorMessage = null)] I get an error:

> Either ErrorMessageString or ErrorMessageResourceName must be set, but
>   not both.

How can I highlight the textbox without showing an error message while still allowing error messages for other validations?

Comment: if you want to keep both [Required] and [your highlight stuff], i guess there are two ways to achieve that. First, is to create a new attribute(custom attribte) and add that also to the fields. Second is use Jquery, easy and fast. Moreover just one or two lines of code will do it for all the fields.

Comment: Why don't you just make the error message and empty string?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, as well. The error you're getting is because `Required` does not accept `null` for those parameters, but it will accept an empty string, because it's still a string. Should effectively at least give the appearance that the error message is removed, as it will display the empty string.

Comment: You get the same error if you set ErrorMessage = ""

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "First Name must not be more than 40 characters.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a reliable way to hack into the validation process, but you could hack into the form submission process like this (Off the top of my head and untested) :

```
$("#theForm").submit(function () {
    $('.validation-summary-errors').hide();
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        $('.validation-summary-errors>ul>li').filter(function(){
            return (/The FirstName field is required/i).test($(this).text())
        }).hide();
    }
    $('.validation-summary-errors').show();
});
```

The concept is: if the form is not valid, if "The FirstName field is required" shows up in the validation summary, hide it. Prevent it from flashing by hiding the whole block first.