# How do highlight a field but not show the validation message in fluent validation

Tags: jquery, validation, fluentvalidation

I have a validation wrapping social security number (ssn) boxes.  Three different boxes to be precise.  Ideally I would like to have the following behavior; if a box is blank it should be hightlighted as missing information but only one message stating the ssn is missing.

Code:

```
        RuleFor(m => m.Ssnumber1)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Social security number required");

        RuleFor(m => m.Ssnumber2)
            .NotEmpty()
            .When(m => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Ssnumber1))
            .WithMessage("Social security number required")
            .NotEmpty()
            .When(m => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Ssnumber1))
            .WithMessage("I don't want a message just highlight");
     ................ the third ssn box is just the same .............
```

Adding the WithMessage(string.empty) or any equivalent results in an error because it expects an actual message.  But if I don't add any message (no WithMessage) it does not highlight the field.  If I add an actual message it shows up and clutters the validation message list since one ssn message is sufficient.

I think I may have the same issue as this guy: [Only highlight required fields without showing an error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046233/only-highlight-required-fields-without-showing-an-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a rule without a message and just style the input that has the error.

Normally in your views the input that has a validation error will have the following class 'input-validation-error', you could simply include this css rule to you view

```
input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This would result in the all the inputs with validation errors to be highlighted in red.

Additionally you could do

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: red;
}
```

if you want to highlight the validation message as well. Or even do a display: none to hide it.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to *this* question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.